# Encoding to h264 failed to send some frames using ffmpeg c api

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

Using FFMPEG C API, Im trying to push generated image to MP4 format.

When I push frame-by-frame, the muxing seems to failed on `avcodec_receive_packet(...)` which return `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` on the first frames, but after a while is starting to add my frame, but the first one.

What I mean, is that when push frame 1 to 13, I have errors, but after frame 14 to end (36), the frame are added to the video, but the encoded image are not the 14 to 36, instead its the frame 1 to 23 that are added.

I don't understand, is this a problem with the framerate (which i want 12 fps), or with key/inter- frame?

Here the code for different part of the class,

NOTE:

- m_filename = "C:\tmp\test.mp4"
- m_framerate = 12
- m_width = 1080
- m_height = 1080

**ctor**

```
// Allocate the temporary buffer that hold the our generated image in RGB.
picture_rgb24 = av_frame_alloc();
picture_rgb24->pts = 0;
picture_rgb24->data[0] = NULL;
picture_rgb24->linesize[0] = -1;
picture_rgb24->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
picture_rgb24->height = m_height;
picture_rgb24->width = m_width;

if ((_ret = av_image_alloc(picture_rgb24->data, picture_rgb24->linesize, m_width, m_height, (AVPixelFormat)picture_rgb24->format, 24)) < 0)
    throw ...

// Allocate the temporary frame that will be convert from RGB to YUV using ffmpeg api.
frame_yuv420 = av_frame_alloc();
frame_yuv420->pts = 0;
frame_yuv420->data[0] = NULL;
frame_yuv420->linesize[0] = -1;
frame_yuv420->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
frame_yuv420->width = m_height;
frame_yuv420->height = m_width;

if ((_ret = av_image_alloc(frame_yuv420->data, frame_yuv420->linesize, m_width, m_height, (AVPixelFormat)frame_yuv420->format, 32)) < 0)
    throw ...

init_muxer(); // see below.

m_inited = true;
    
m_pts_increment = av_rescale_q(1, { 1, m_framerate }, ofmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base);

// Context that convert the RGB24 to YUV420P format (using this instead of filter similar to GIF).
swsCtx = sws_getContext(m_width, m_height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, m_width, m_height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);
```

**init_muxer:**

```
AVOutputFormat* oformat = av_guess_format(nullptr, m_filename.c_str(), nullptr);
if (!oformat) throw ...

_ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, oformat, nullptr, m_filename.c_str());
if (_ret) throw ...

AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(oformat->video_codec);
if (!codec) throw ...

AVStream *stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, codec);
if (!stream) throw ...

o_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if (!o_codec_ctx) throw ...

stream->codecpar->codec_id = oformat->video_codec;
stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
stream->codecpar->width = m_width;
stream->codecpar->height = m_height;
stream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
stream->codecpar->bit_rate = 400000;

avcodec_parameters_to_context(o_codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
o_codec_ctx->time_base = { 1, m_framerate };

// Using gop_size == 0, we want 'intra' frame, so no b-frame will be generated.
o_codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
o_codec_ctx->gop_size = 0;
o_codec_ctx->b_quant_offset = 0;
//o_codec_ctx->framerate = { m_framerate , 1 };

if (stream->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
    av_opt_set(o_codec_ctx, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);      // Lossless H.264
else if (stream->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H265)
    av_opt_set(o_codec_ctx, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);      // Lossless H.265

avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, o_codec_ctx);

if ((_ret = avcodec_open2(o_codec_ctx, codec, NULL)) < 0)
    throw ...

if ((_ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, m_filename.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0)
    throw ...

if ((_ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0)
    throw ...

av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, m_filename.c_str(), 1);
```

**add_frame:**

```
// loop to transfer our image format to ffmpeg one.
for (int y = 0; y < m_height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < m_width; x++)
    {
        picture_rgb24->data[0][idx] = ...;
        picture_rgb24->data[0][idx + 1] = ...;
        picture_rgb24->data[0][idx + 2] = ...;
    }
}

// From RGB to YUV
sws_scale(swsCtx, (const uint8_t * const *)picture_rgb24->data, picture_rgb24->linesize, 0, m_height, frame_yuv420->data, frame_yuv420->linesize);

// mux the YUV frame
muxing_one_frame(frame_yuv420);

// Increment the FPS of the picture for the next add-up to the buffer.      
picture_rgb24->pts += m_pts_increment;
frame_yuv420->pts += m_pts_increment;
```

**muxing_one_frame:**

```
int ret = avcodec_send_frame(o_codec_ctx, frame);
AVPacket *pkt = av_packet_alloc();
av_init_packet(pkt);

while (ret >= 0) {
    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(o_codec_ctx, pkt);
    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) break;        
    av_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
}
av_packet_unref(pkt);
```

**close_file:**

```
av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
avio_close(ofmt_ctx->pb);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg avcodec\_receive\_packet return -11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246263/ffmpeg-avcodec-receive-packet-return-11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation. https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavc__encdec.html

Or look look at one of many other times this has been answered:

[ffmpeg avcodec_receive_packet return -11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246263/ffmpeg-avcodec-receive-packet-return-11)

[FFmpeg - avcodec_receive_frame returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354120/ffmpeg-avcodec-receive-frame-returns-averroreagain)

[ffmpeg function avcodec_receive_frame always return EAGAIN error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133098/ffmpeg-function-avcodec-receive-frame-always-return-eagain-error)

Comment: is there a way to enforce "intra" frame and dont have any B/P frame ? I just want to encode everything. But I think, I catch the problem, the issue is caused by the codec that required more frame to encode.

Comment: I tried this before, like pushing as much frame as possible, and continue until the end, but with further read of your topic, I realized that I forget to pass the null frame at the end to mark the end of the video! I think this is the issue! I will check on that. Thanks